# C++: [class] was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, operator-keyword

---------------------Queue.h--------------------

```
#ifndef QUEUE_H
#define QUEUE_H

#include <iostream>
#include "MyException.h"

using namespace std;

template<class T>
class Queue;

template<class T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream&,Queue<T>&);

template<class T>
class Queue
{
    public:
        friend ostream& operator<< <T>(ostream&,Queue<T>&);
        Queue();
        Queue(const Queue<T>& other);
        Queue<T>& operator=(const Queue<T>& other);
        ~Queue();
    void enqueue(const T& el);
        T dequeue();
        void increasePriority(const T& el);
        bool isEmpty();

    private:
        class Node
        {
            public:
                Node(const T& data, Node* n = 0)
                {
                    element = data;
                    next = n;
                }

                T element;
                Node* next;
        };
        Node* head;

};

#include "Queue.C"

#endif
```

We're not allowed to change the .h (above) file at all.

---------------------Queue.C--------------------

```
 #include "Queue.h"

    template<class T>
    ostream& operator << (ostream &strm, Queue<T> &obj)
    {
        if (obj.isEmpty())
        {
            strm << "[]";
            return strm;
        }
        else
        {
            strm << '[';
 //line 28
    Node* tmp = new Node();
            tmp = obj.head;
            strm << tmp.element + ',';
            while (tmp->next != 0)
            {
                tmp = tmp->next;
                if (tmp-next != 0)
                {
                    strm << tmp.element + ',';
                }
                else
                {
                    strm << tmp.element;
                }
            }
            strm << ']';
            delete [] tmp;
            tmp = 0;
            return strm;
        }
        return strm;
    }
    //...more code
    Queue::Queue()
    {
//line 54
    head = new Node();
        }
```

So from that code some of the errors I receive are as follow:

```
Queue.C: In function ‘std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, Queue<T>&)’:
Queue.C:28: error: ‘Node’ was not declared in this scope
Queue.C:28: error: ‘tmp’ was not declared in this scope
Queue.C:28: error: expected type-specifier before ‘Node’
Queue.C:28: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘Node’
Queue.C:34: error: ‘next’ was not declared in this scope
Queue.C: At global scope:

Queue.C:54: error: ‘head’ was not declared in this scope
Queue.C:54: error: expected type-specifier before ‘Node’
Queue.C:54: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘Node’
```

Comment: `Node` is part of `Queue`.

Comment: You don't need to include the header file in the source file, as the source file is included in the header file.

Answer (score 1):

You are including `Queue.h` in `Queue.C`, and vice versa. You should not include `Queue.h` in `Queue.C`, since you want the whole implementation to be accessible from the header.

Next, `Node` is declared inside `Queue`, so in the implementation it has to be prefixed with the scope of the `Queue` class template:

```
Queue<T>::Node ...; // instead of Node
```

Answer (score 1):

You must prefix `Node` with the scope it was defined in, namely `Queue`

```
Queue<T>::Node* tmp = new Queue<T>::Node();
```

otherwise the compiler doesn't know which `Node` type you mean.

But in the next line, you overwrite your `tmp` pointer with `obj.head` and lose your newly created `Node`. This will result in a memory leak. In any case, you shouldn't need to create new `Node`s in an operator, which only outputs a Queue.

Further down, you

```
delete [] tmp;
```

which deletes the last element in your Queue. I suppose, you shouldn't modify the Queue in any way in this output operator.

Which leads to the next point, this operator should be declared

```
friend ostream& operator<< <T>(ostream&, const Queue<T>&);
```

to avoid modifying the Queue object accidentally.